# update textarea value, but keep cursor position

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html textarea that will be updated periodically via javascript.

when I do this:

```
$("#textarea").val(new_val);
```

The cursor moves to the end of the text.

I would like to update the text without changing the cursor position. Also, if the user has a range of text selected, the highlight should be preserved.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a pair of functions that get and set the selection/caret position in a text area in all major browsers.

Note: if you don't need to support IE <= 8, just use the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement)). All of the complicated code below is just there to support old versions of IE.

```
function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}

function offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, offset) {
    return offset - (el.value.slice(0, offset).split("\r\n").length - 1);
}

function setInputSelection(el, startOffset, endOffset) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = startOffset;
        el.selectionEnd = endOffset;
    } else {
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        var startCharMove = offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, startOffset);
        range.collapse(true);
        if (startOffset == endOffset) {
            range.move("character", startCharMove);
        } else {
            range.moveEnd("character", offsetToRangeCharacterMove(el, endOffset));
            range.moveStart("character", startCharMove);
        }
        range.select();
    }
}
```

When you change the textarea's value, first save the selection, then restore it afterwards:

```
var t = document.getElementById("textarea");
var sel = getInputSelection(t);
t.value = some_new_value;
setInputSelection(t, sel.start, sel.end);
```

Comment: Does the `setInputSelection` function work only in IE? I'm asking because the `createTextRange` method does not exist (for input elements) in the other browsers, so that an error is thrown.

Comment: I created a demo using your code. The code is here: http://vidasp.net/js/selection.js and the demo is here: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/select-demo.html The demo works flawlessly in IE9 beta, Chrome and Safari. However, there is an issue in Firefox: If you set the selection programmatically ( `selec.set(input, 10, 20);` it wont work **unless** you focus the  text-box ( `input.focus();` ). In my demo, I am focusing the text-box after setting the selection - just to make it work in Firefox. Therefore, consider placing `el.focus()` at the end of the `setInputSelection` function.

Comment: Is this still the best way to handle this? I came across this code in an older project and it seems really long/complicated for such a seemingly simple task

Comment: @Marie: The complication is just there for IE <= 8. You can lose nearly all of it and just use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` if you don't need to support IE 8.

Comment: One note - `typeof NaN === 'number'` comes out to `true`. This happens to not hit that boundary case, but in case anyone messes around with the code, they should know that it'd be stronger to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

A decade later but this is what I came up with for replacing items in a textarea.  Some additional handling is needed to adjust the caret or selection when replacing with longer or shorter text.

```js
// find and replace in textarea while preserving caret and selection
function replaceText(el, findText, replaceWithText) {
    var text = el.value;
    var selectionStart = 0;
    var selectionEnd = 0;
  // only support modern browsers for preserving caret and selection
    if (el.setSelectionRange) {
        selectionStart = el.selectionStart;
        selectionEnd = el.selectionEnd;
    }
    var start = 0;
    while ((start = text.indexOf(findText, start)) > -1) {
        var end = start + findText.length;
        text = text.substr(0, start) + replaceWithText + text.substr(end);
        if (selectionStart < end) {
            selectionStart = Math.min(selectionStart, start + replaceWithText.length);
        } else {
            selectionStart = selectionStart + replaceWithText.length - (end - start);
        }
        if (selectionEnd < end) {
            selectionEnd = Math.min(selectionEnd, start + replaceWithText.length);
        } else {
            selectionEnd = selectionEnd + replaceWithText.length - (end - start);
        }
        start += replaceWithText.length;
    }
  // don't do anything unless we need to (otherwise destroys undo)
    if (el.value != text) { 
        el.value = text;
        if (el.setSelectionRange) {
            el.selectionStart = selectionStart;
            el.selectionEnd = selectionEnd;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
Place caret on or after the word LONGER, or select some text after or including it:
<br />
<textarea id='t'>Here is
some LONGERtext
to replace</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="replaceText(document.getElementById('t'),'LONGER',''); document.getElementById('t').focus();" value="remove word LONGER" />
```