# Replacing selected text in the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the best way to do this in jQuery? This should be a fairly common use case.

1. User selects text in a textarea
2. He clicks on a link
3. The text in the link replaces the selected text in the textarea

Any code will be much appreciated - I am having some issues with part 3.

Comment: The properties `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` of your `textarea` or `input` is all you need nowadays. Combine that with the `slice` method on the input element's value.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's how you can do it, in all major browsers. I've also got a [jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs) that includes this functionality. With that, the code would be

```
$("your_textarea_id").replaceSelectedText("NEW TEXT");
```

Here's a full stand-alone solution:

```
function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range,
        textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}

function replaceSelectedText(el, text) {
    var sel = getInputSelection(el), val = el.value;
    el.value = val.slice(0, sel.start) + text + val.slice(sel.end);
}

var el = document.getElementById("your_textarea");
replaceSelectedText(el, "[NEW TEXT]");
```

Comment: This will be an amazingly useful plugin. Thank you so much! It is kinda weird how this use case is not covered yet. I tried writing my own, but hit on so many browser quirks. ;)

Comment: replaceSelectedText - the only issue i see with this is that in IE, when nothing is selected, the cursor goes to the front, as opposed to the end. anyway that can be fixed?

Comment: In the code posted here or the jQuery plugin? The code here makes no attempt to reposition the selection afterwards, for the sake of brevity. The jQuery plugin should deal with that.

Comment: @TimDown thats a great bit of code, but why the heck is this not in the jquery libs already.  I'm with Ming, I would have thought this was a fairly common use case.

Comment: @Ads: They like to keep the core lean. I can understand that.

Comment: Add these to the end of the replaceSelectedText() function to make sure the carat gets properly placed at the end of the inserted text:

el.selectionStart = sel.start + text.length;
el.selectionEnd = el.selectionStart;

Comment: @JimCarnicelli: There is complication in old IE for that as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3288215/96100

Comment: Please note that [the linked library is not yet open source](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs/issues/16).

Comment: This is such a GREAT Plugin!

Answer (score 3):

Building on caw's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964710/replacing-selected-text-in-the-textarea#comment71421624_3964710), this is much easier to do in 2023:

```js
link.onclick = () => {
  let first = textarea.value.slice(0, textarea.selectionStart);
  let rest = textarea.value.slice(textarea.selectionEnd, textarea.value.length);

  textarea.value = first + link.innerText + rest;

  // Bonus: place cursor behind replacement
  textarea.selectionEnd = (first + link.innerText).length;
};
```

It's essentially [Tim Down's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3966822/1371131), only trimmed down to what you need when you assume that `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are available on text inputs.

Not sure what you mean by "text in the link". For now, I'm using `link.innerText`.

Why you'd need jQuery for this, I don't know, but you could easily use `$(link).on('click', ...)` or whatever instead.