# Replacing highlighted text inside a text area

Tags: javascript, string, selection, str-replace

### This question already has an answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964710/replacing-selected-text-in-the-textarea)

---

I am searching for some way to replace highlighted text that is inside a text area with a new string that has already been defined.

I can get everything in the text area with:

`var all_text = document.activeElement.value;`

and I can get the highlighted text with:

`var selected_text = window.getSelection().toString();`

**But how can I replace the selected text with a new string?**

I have seen many related questions on this site, but every solution I have seen so far just says to use `str.replace()`.

I do not want to simply use `str.replace()`because **if there are multiple instances of** **`selected_text`** **contained within the text area, it can result undesirable behavior.**

[image]

I need to supplement the function with additional test conditions to ensure that only the selected text gets replaced and not some other string that happened to be equivalent to its `toString()` value.

I thought I could make use of the `anchorOffest` property of `selection` objects, but the property doesn't seem to work in chrome. In fact most of the `selection` properties don't seem to be working.

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964710/replacing-selected-text-in-the-textarea

Comment: show ur code... without ur code.. it is hard to guess what you really want

Comment: @SehoLee It should already be clear what I want if you read it again

Comment: what exactly isn't working in the linked answer?

Comment: @Rhumborl Its not replacing the selected text, but Its is not giving me any error messages, so I am not sure at this point

Comment: @Rhumborl  I just uninatalled and reinstalled my extension and It works now! I swear it wasn't working last night...

Answer (score 0):

if selected_text has a local scope, you really don't have to worry about 
creating multiple instances because js garbage collector will do the job. 
If selected_text has a global scope, it is a singleton. 
But.. if you are really really concern about creating multiple instances, 
just save your value to the text tag attribute
I am not sure how ur code is working but below is my suggestion.

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text.setAttribute("selected_text", false);
text.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    var all_text = document.activeElement.value;
    this.setAttribute("selected_text", window.getSelection().toString());
    //if you need to send highlighted value
    var txt = this.getAttribute("selected_text");
    sendHightlightedTxt(txt);
});
```