# Why Can't I Deep Copy an Event Object?

Tags: javascript

I have an onPaste event. I am trying to deep copy it using the standard methods, e.g.

```
_.cloneDeep(pasteEvent)
```

or

```
Object.assign({}, pasteEvent)
```

or

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pasteEvent))
```

It returns as empty object (lodash) or an object with one property (the other two methods). The event that I can't copy:

[image]

Comment: What problem you're solving that requires a deep clone of a host object?

Comment: Both `Object.assign` and `JSON.stringify` will only visit *own* properties that are *enumerable*.

Comment: @zerkms: I am trying to cancel and re-issue a paste event, with changed paste content. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848003/set-preventdefault-back-to-false-on-javascript-event I later found out that I CANNOT create a clipboard event in Chrome (can find source if interested). So I have to resort to copying an existing event. Ideally, I would just change some props, but they are immutable. The root of the problem is that I need to "preventDefault" on the original event, but I need the event I reissue to have preventDefault: false;

Comment: "I later found out that I CANNOT create a clipboard event" --- does not this automatically mean you cannot deep-clone it? If you cannot create something -> you cannot clone it.

Comment: @zerkms I don't get this. I thought everything, including events, was "just an object." I understand a constructor not being provided, but not being able to clone an object is weird.