# JavaScript paste event on selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paste

### Problem:

I want to format incoming text via paste, but the approach I am taking only allows to replace existing text, or add to it, thus *selected text is intacted*.

So how to get selected text on paste event.

I don't care for cross browser support.

---

How should it look like:

- text inside textarea: aa 1**2 56 99**<-selected text
- text in clipboard:56abccda6
- text output:aa 15 6a bc cda6

---

JavaScript/jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function isHex(h) {
        let a = parseInt(h,16);
        return (a.toString(16) ===h.toLowerCase())
    }
    function formatText(text) {
        if(isHex(text)){
            let splitedText = text.match(/[\s\S]{1,2}/g) || [];
            splitedText = splitedText.join(' ');
            return splitedText;
        }
        return text;
    }
    $('textarea[name=plainText]').on('paste', function(event) {
        let formatedText = formatText(event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text'));
        $(this).val($(this).val() + formatedText);
        //or
        //  $(this).val(formatedText);
        return false;
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Message" name="plainText" id="plainText" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Message'"></textarea>
```

Comment: @L_Church ummmm...isn't OP already using paste event?

Comment: woah he is my bad. rofl

Comment: It might be a cross browser issue ... What browser do you want it to be working?

Comment: You never say, in the script, that the selected text should be replaced. In fact you tell it to add it after the existing text. So it does what you tell it to do.

Comment: Duplicate question, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3966822/1397220)

Comment: Yup, didn't look good enough. Thank you @Brainfeeder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('textarea[name=plainText]').on('paste', function(event) {
            let formatedText = 
        formatText(event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text'));
        $("#plainText").replaceSelectedText(formatedText);
            return false;
        })
});
```