# Autoformat SSN while entering the number

Tags: javascript

I have a textfield and the user enters the SSN number. While entering itself it should format. Like On the change of the textField... it should format `999-999-999` in this way on the display itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<input id="ssn"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ssn').keyup(function() {
        var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        val = val.replace(/^(\d{3})/, '$1-');
        val = val.replace(/-(\d{2})/, '-$1-');
        val = val.replace(/(\d)-(\d{4}).*/, '$1-$2');
        this.value = val;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually the social security number are in format of `000-00-0000`.

Comment: I've updated my solution to match `NNN-NN-NNNN` pattern.

Comment: This is almost there, but from what I've tried, it has two problems. First, whenever you hit a key in the middle of the ssn, the cursor goes to the end of the text. Second, unless you hold the 'delete' key down, when you click 'delete' on a dash it reappears right away. I've fixed the second one with a solution I'll show below, but I've hit a wall with the first one.

Answer (score 29):

The script from @kottenator was almost there, but it breaks the value every 3 digits, instead of 3, then 2, like the 000-00-0000 needed for Social Security numbers.

I did a little editing and modified it to work as intended. Hope this helps.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#ssn1').keyup(function() {
          var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
          var newVal = '';
          if(val.length > 4) {
             this.value = val;
          }
          if((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
             newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
             val = val.substr(3);
          }
          if (val.length > 5) {
             newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
             newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
             val = val.substr(5);
           }
           newVal += val;
           this.value = newVal.substring(0, 11);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I like how it also limits the number of characters that you can put in

Comment: I've just read this solution, 2 years later :) Yes, my code formats the output as `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}` but that's how it was requested in the question. For some reason I've forgot how many chars does SSN have. Thanks, @Dennis O'Neil / @Jason Hansen.

Answer (score 7):

@Dennis's answer was the best here, however it used JQuery to do the selector and the OP did not have a JQuery tag on this post, just JavaScript. Here is the VanillaJS version of the solution (or at least one way to do it :)

```
document.getElementById("ssn").onkeyup = function() {
  var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var newVal = '';

  if(val.length > 4) {
    this.value = val;
  }

  if((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
    newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
    val = val.substr(3);
  }

  if (val.length > 5) {
    newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
    newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
    val = val.substr(5);
  }

  newVal += val;
  this.value = newVal;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

@Rost's answer is a great start, but had three flaws. In this answer I've fixed two of them. Flaws:

1. When you try to delete a '-' it immediately reappeared. That's fixed.
2. When the user types something wrong, the wrong text was there for a second before going away. That's also fixed.
3. When you change the text in any way, the cursor moves to the end of the text. That's still a problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288215/3791179 is the best suggestion I've found to try to fix that last problem. It doesn't work here, though, because we're changing how many characters are in the value. I haven't worked out the math to make it work properly yet. If I do, I'll edit this answer.

```
<input id="ssn"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $( "#ssn" ).on("input", function() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    val = val.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2');
    val = val.replace(/^(\d{3})-(\d{2})(.+)/, '$1-$2-$3');
    this.value = val.substring(0, 11);
  });
</script>
```

I don't think the `input` event is supported in all versions of all browsers. You can use the `keyup` event instead, but I can't find info on how many browsers support that. If you do, problem #2 will come back, but that might be fine. Some users might find it helpful to see what they're doing wrong.

Comment: @knod Just curious, how would you allow the user to type in the dash?
As it is if the user types in the dash, it is automatically removed.
<br>
After getting the substring, I tried `formattedValue.length === 3 ? `${formattedValue}-` : formattedValue;`<br>
But, that actually causes an issue when backspacing, so that the dash is not able to be deleted.

Comment: That's a great point. @NateThompson. It'll take some thinking, though. I'll give it a shot when I have a chance. Off the top of my head, for those who want to play around, I'd experiment with replacing the regex in line 5 with something like `/[^0-9-]/g`, the regex in line 6 with something like `/^(\d{3})-*(\d{1,2})/`, and line 7 with `/^(\d{3})-(\d{2})-*(\d{1,4})/`. Don't quote me on that. Honestly, there are plenty of improvement to make here.

Comment: I had the same issue and posted a variation that allows folks to type or delete the dashes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515230/244368

Answer (score 3):

@knod has the best answer here, but their solution had a drawback where folks couldn't type in their own dashes.

I modified their answer to allow users to (optionally) type or delete their own dashes and avoid blocking valid input (and added some comments to explain each step).

```js
function formatSSN(ssn) {
  // remove all non-dash and non-numerals
  var val = ssn.replace(/[^\d-]/g, '');

  // add the first dash if number from the second group appear
  val = val.replace(/^(\d{3})-?(\d{1,2})/, '$1-$2');

  // add the second dash if numbers from the third group appear
  val = val.replace(/^(\d{3})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{1,4})/, '$1-$2-$3');

  // remove misplaced dashes
  val = val.split('').filter((val, idx) => {
    return val !== '-' || idx === 3 || idx === 6;
  }).join('');

  // enforce max length
  return val.substring(0, 11);
}

// bind our function
document.getElementById("ssn").onkeyup = function(e) {
  this.value = formatSSN(this.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Karl. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

I modified Dennis' script a bit removing the jquery elements. Not sure why the first two if clauses were added, so I removed them from this function. This function is a listener for the Titanium SDK using underscore.js. But you should be able to modify it to work with other JS API's.

```
$.usernameField.addEventListener('blur', function(param) {

    var inputString = param.value;

    if (inputString.length === 9 && _.isNumber(parseInt(inputString, 10))) {

        var val = inputString.replace(/\D/g, '');

        var outputString = '';

        outputString += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        outputString += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
        val = val.substr(5);
        outputString += val;

        $.usernameField.value = outputString;

    }
});
```

Comment: The OP only listed JavaScript in their tag. You should try to not mix in other API's in your answer since they might not know anything about Titanium SDK and underscore.js

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    var sizes = [3, 2, 4];

    for (var i in sizes) {
      if (val.length > sizes[i]) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, sizes[i]) + '-';
        val = val.substr(sizes[i]);
      }
      else
        break;        
    }

    newVal += val;
    this.value = newVal;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{1,3})(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,4})?/).slice(1, 4).filter(el=>!!el).join('-'));
}catch{}
```