# Angular 2- Change text display format as per pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I want to change display format of text field input for Mobile number.
Ex.

For number 1212121212, it should display (121) 212-1212 inside text and just for view purpose only. I also want full text on insert it into the DB.
How can i achieve this in Angular 2 text input?

```html
<p>How it is now</p>
<input type="text" value="1212121212" name="mobile"><br>
<p>How it should look</p>
<input type="text" value="(121) 212-1212" name="mobile2">
```

Comment: is this value always a fixed length?

Comment: Not sure. But can we try pattern for first 6 char? After '-' i don't care about length of numbers

Comment: checkout pipes in angular

Comment: @jai label is alright but what about input field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 {pipes} - How to format a phone number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895431/angular2-pipes-how-to-format-a-phone-number)

Comment: Use keydown event to replace value according to your pattern. Then when time has come to retrieve the raw value, replace everything but digits with an empty string.

Comment: @HMarteau Pipe is used for displayed data. But i want to use it inside text field

Comment: Hope this helps. [autoformat-ssn-while-entering-the-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685175/autoformat-ssn-while-entering-the-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do **[something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2b88ps?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)** with a pipe (just add a number at the end of the input).

I'm of course using a very simple regex, but you can create the one you want.

```
transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
  const regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
  const match = value.match(regex);
  if(match) {
    return `(${match[1]})${match[2]}-${match[3]}`;
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Just one question. Is it possible to start patterning from the first latter instead of 10 letters? Here after inserting 10 digits it is changing it's view.

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you, for that you will need a monstruous regex (or several little regexes).

Comment: as a piece of advice, if you use several little regexes, start with the biggest one, and finish with the simplest one. Otherwise, you might be surprised by the results you get.