# Stop cursor from jumping to end of input field in javascript replace

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm using a regular expression to strip invalid characters out of an text input area in javascript (running in IE). I run the replace function on every keyup event. However, this makes the cursor jump to the end of the text box after each keypress, which makes inline editing impossible.

Here is it in action:

http://jsbin.com/ifufuv/2

Does anyone know how to make it so the cursor does not jump to the end of the input box?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you choose a better event to handle.  `onkeyup` is poor for detecting user input.  See http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript.

Comment: Here's a fully realised example of how to maintain the selection when replacing the value of a textarea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position/3288215#3288215

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to manually put the cursor back where you want it.  For IE9, set `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd` (or use `.setSelectionRange(start, end)`).  For IE8 and earlier, use `.createTextRange()` and call `.moveStart()` on the text range.

Comment: W3Schools have a wonderful example on how to use onkeypress to cancel keys (in their example, it cancels numbers, and you seem sufficiently capable to modify the regex to take out the characters you don't want). http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: @Mike: W3Schools doesn't really deserve people like you promoting their website for them.  Take a look at http://w3fools.com - a lot of information at w3s is wrong or promoting bad practices for developers.  There are much better resources on the web, like http://quirksmode.org or http://developer.mozilla.org.

Comment: Fair enough point, I was unaware of the issues with that site.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position/3288215#3288215 for my implementation of this basic technique.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to [gilly3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219711/2680216), I thought someone might find it useful to see an actual code snippet.

In the example below, the `selectionStart` property is retrieved from the `input` element prior to the JavaScript string manipulation. Then `selectionStart` is set back to the initial position *after* the manipulation.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could also access `selectionEnd` in place of `selectionStart`, and set a range: `setSelectionRange(start, end)`.

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var target = e.target,
      position = target.selectionStart; // Capture initial position
  
  target.value = target.value.replace(/\s/g, '');  // This triggers the cursor to move.
  
  target.selectionEnd = position;    // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
});
```

```html
<p>The method <code>.replace()</code> will move the cursor's position, but you won't notice this.</p>
<input type="text" id="target" />
```

Comment: I did a quick gist based on your code with a function to refactor easily https://gist.github.com/romuleald/f1b980d5ad01b9f525e8e0244f91711a

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work with input type="email".

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, I found https://www.sitepoint.com/6-jquery-cursor-functions/ had the solution. here are 6 methods that will allow you to get/set the cursor position in an input/textarea. I believe this will work for content editable fields as well!

This was very helpful as the bug only showed for IE and Windows 7 combination.

Here is my Before code

```
$body.on('input paste','.replace-special-chars',function () {
    let coma = /‚/g;
    let doubleQuotes = /[“”]/g;
    let singleQuotes = /[‘’]/g;
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(doubleQuotes,'"'));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(coma,','));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(singleQuotes,"'"));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g, '- '));
});
```

and my after code which utilizes the jquery methods that I found on the website I stated above

```
$body.on('input paste','.replace-special-chars',function () {
    let position = $(this).getCursorPosition();
    let coma = /‚/g;
    let doubleQuotes = /[“”]/g;
    let singleQuotes = /[‘’]/g;
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(doubleQuotes,'"'));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(coma,','));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(singleQuotes,"'"));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g, '- '));
    $(this).setCursorPosition(position);
});
```