# jQuery Mask Plugin: mask for negative integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-mask

I am using [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) in my web project. It is used widely and I don't want to change it for now.

I use the following mask for the numbers with decimal separators:

For example for the element:

```
<input class="number-field" value="123456">
```

I use the following mask:

```
$('input.number-field').mask('#,##0', {'reverse': true});
```

It works for **positive** numbers, but now I would like to add support of ***negative*** numbers.

Neither of the following patterns work:

```
$('input.number-field').mask('#,##0Z', {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    'Z': {
      pattern: /\-?/
    }
  }
})

$('input.number-field').mask('Z#,##0', {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    'Z': {
      pattern: /\-?/
    }
  }
})

$('input.number-field').mask('Z#,##0', {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    'Z': {
      pattern: /-/,
      optional: true
    }
  }
})
```

Last one seems working, but only for 4 digits in the line.

How can I use this plugin for negative numbers? I may consider even patching this plugin if someone can propose an idea.

You can try it with [jsFiddle template](https://jsfiddle.net/fq8r5jvf/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I expanded off of your last attempt and translated the special `#` character to recursively accept digits and dashes (i.e., `/[\d-]/`). Then I changed the masking pattern to `#,##0`.

Since the plugin doesn't allow you to add negative/positive lookaheads in the regular expression pattern, I added an `onChange` callback to prevent `-` characters from being anywhere but the beginning of the string.

- `.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')` - This will remove all of the `-` characters that are not at the beginning of the line.
- `.replace(/^,/, '')` - This will remove leading `,` characters (i.e., it would remove the `,` from a string like `,123`).
- `.replace(/^-,/, '-')` - This will remove `,` characters directly following `-` characters (i.e., it would remove `,` from `-,123`).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/oucz6r1p/)

```js
$('input.number-field').mask('#,##0', {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    '#': {
      pattern: /-|\d/,
      recursive: true
    }
  },
  onChange: function(value, e) {      
    e.target.value = value.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '').replace(/^,/, '').replace(/^-,/, '-');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input class="number-field" value="123456">
```

Additionally, if you want to [prevent the cursor indicator from jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219639/stop-cursor-from-jumping-to-end-of-input-field-in-javascript-replace/29440988#29440988) to the end of the string when replacing the characters, you could leverage the code from my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219639/stop-cursor-from-jumping-to-end-of-input-field-in-javascript-replace/29440988#29440988).

```js
$('input.number-field').mask('#,##0', {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    '#': {
      pattern: /-|\d/,
      recursive: true
    }
  },
  onChange: function(value, e) {
    var target = e.target,
        position = target.selectionStart; // Capture initial position

    target.value = value.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '').replace(/^,/, '').replace(/^-,/, '-');

    target.selectionEnd = position; // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input class="number-field" value="123456">
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine! I only made some modifications to work with non-input elements too. Just check `$(target).prop("tagName") == 'INPUT'` and use `innerHTML` instead of `value` otherwise.

Comment: My only criticism is that in order to put in a negative number, you have to hit the [Home] key *after* you put in the raw numerical value, otherwise the `0` at the end of the mask (`#,##0`) prevents you from entering the negative value in any other way. I wish there was a way to capture any entered value *after* the first one entered, and if it is a negative sign, punt it to the front of the number. That way, you could enter “254-” and it would end up as “-254” automagically. Otherwise, excellent answer! Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just choose a character to translate signal, im my case Z.

```
$("#input").mask("Z0999999.00", {

   translation: {
     '0': {pattern: /\d/},
     '9': {pattern: /\d/, optional: true},
     'Z': {pattern: /[\-\+]/, optional: true}
   }

});
```

And put the mask on input.

```
<input id="input"/>
```

Comment: Does it work with a decimal separator? I would like to see the number "-123456789.12" as "-123,456,789.12". How do you do this?

Comment: To do it, you can use reverse input. But have a problem, you need to put the sign after input the number, moving the cursor to the first number character.

look here : https://embed.plnkr.co/RnfflU31V0XMtO4CEgsm/

Comment: You can do a trick to put cursor in the first position and the sign character will work fine.

look this plunkr, https://plnkr.co/edit/RnfflU31V0XMtO4CEgsm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In my case i needed the thousands separator to be a

> ,

and the decimal to be

> .

I also wanted to be able to set the value to negative any time. and if the value already in the input before pressing minus was 12 i wanted it to result in -12 and so on.

In the end i ended up with

```js
    function DecimalMaskPTBR(element) {
      element.mask("#.##X,XX", {
        reverse: true,
        translation: {
          "#": {
            pattern: /-|\d/,
            recursive: true
          },
          "X": {
            pattern: /-|\d/,
            recursive: false
          }
        },
        onChange: function(value, e) {
          var target = e.target,
            position = target.selectionStart; // Capture initial position
          if (value.length > 1 && e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.data == "-") {
            value = value.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/\./g, '');
            var decimalpos = value.length - value.indexOf(',');
            if (value.length > 1 && decimalpos == 2) {
              var pos = value.length - 3;
              value = value.replace(/,/g, '');
              value = value.substring(0, pos) + "," + value.substring(pos);
            }
            target.value = value;
            target.selectionEnd = position;
            value = target.value = "-" + element.masked(target.value);
          }
          target.value = value.replace(/^-,/, '-').replace(/^-\./, '-').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
          target.selectionEnd = position; // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
        }
      });
    }
    $(function() {
      DecimalMaskPTBR($('.number-field'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input class="number-field" value="-123456">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HeitorZ/h0zwp68v/4/)

I based my solution on what @Josh Crozier had already done in his answer

Answer (score 0):

If callback doesnt work you can

```
$(this).find("td.selling").each(function (i, element) {
        $(element).unmask().mask('###.###.###.###.###.###.###.###', {
            reverse: true,
            translation: {
                '#': {
                    pattern: /\-|\d/,
                    recursive: true
                }
            },
        });
        $(element).text($(element).text().replace('-.', '-'));
       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

/* For negative decimal values */

```
$('.money').mask("#.##0,00", {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    '0': { pattern: /\d/ },
    '#': {
      pattern: /\-|\d/, /*signal included*/
      recursive: true
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way:

```js
$('#input').mask('000.000,00', {
            reverse: true,
            translation: { 
                '0': {
                    pattern: /-|\d/,
                    recursive: true
                }
            },
onChange: function(value, e) {
    e.target.value = value.replace(/^-\./, '-').replace(/^-,/, '-').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '');
    }
});
```

If you use de charactere `#`, you can not initialize number with `-`  therfore use `0` to translation

1. `value.replace(/^-\./, '-')` This will change string like `-.` to
   `-`
2. `replace(/^-,/, '-')` This will change string like `-,` to `-`
3. `replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')` This will remove charactere `-` that are
   not at the beginning of the line