# Repeat group of '000,' in jquery mask

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

I'm trying to format values as money in one project, and those values can be negative.

I'm stuck in how to create the correct mask. I did one [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zq1pk154/):

```
<input type="text" class="negative-money" />

$(document).ready(function() {    
  var mask = $('.negative-money');
  var money = -1011987.65;

  mask.val(money);
  mask.mask('-{000,}000.00');
  // ---------^^^^^^ the problem is here
});
```

I looked some examples and read some articles, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I want the output for the previous example to be: `-1,011,987.65`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for negative numbers

[jQuery Mask Plugin: mask for negative integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660995/jquery-mask-plugin-mask-for-negative-integers)

I have modified the script based on the above link:

```
$('input.negative-money').mask('#,##0.00', {
  reverse: true,
  translation: {
    '#': {
      pattern: /-|\d/,
      recursive: true
    }
  }
});

var value = $('input.negative-money').val();
$('input.negative-money').val(value.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '').replace(/^,/, '').replace(/^-,/, '-'));
```