# JQuery input change only specifc word

Tags: jquery, input

I have an input on my HTML code, I want to change only a specific word in this input.

```
<input type="text" value="Input that I want to change only **this** word" id="inpWord">
```

when I keypress on this input, only change the word **this**, when I type/erease other word blocks me.

how can i do this on Jquery?

Comment: Use a `regexp` and `.replace()`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an event listener for the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), which is fired synchronously when the value is changed (including when you paste a value in). If you want to strip out any optional whitespace around the desired word(s), you can replace `/\s*this\s*/g` with `' '`.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\s*this\s*/g, ' ');
});
```

```css
input { width: 100%; line-height: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Input that I want to change only this word">
```

However, you will notice that there is an issue. The input caret will jump to the end of the field while you are typing because the entire value of the `input` element is being updated. To avoid this, you can implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219639/stop-cursor-from-jumping-to-end-of-input-field-in-javascript-replace/29440988#29440988) where the initial position of the caret is captured and then updated after the value is replaced:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  
  // Capture initial position
  var position = target.selectionStart;

  // This triggers the cursor to move.
  target.value = target.value.replace(/\s*this\s*/g, ' ');

  // Set the cursor back to the initial position.
  target.selectionEnd = position;
});
```

```css
input { width: 100%; line-height: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Input that I want to change only this word">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inpWord').on('keyup',function(){
  str = $(this).val().replace('this','that')
  $(this).val(str)
});
```

Comment: Not much explanation needed. If you are typing in an input and you type the word `'this'` then it changes it to `'that'`. That's what the poster wanted.

Comment: then look at the other answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this. It will replace all the instances for you and its case insensitive. It will respond to change, keyup, and paste events. Try it out :-)

```js
$('#replace').on('keyup paste change',function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/this/gi,'that');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="replace">
```