# Cursor is jumping to end position on deletion if character from the middle in input using mask

Tags: html

The cursor is jumping to end position on deletion of character on any position of the input field using mask library.

The code is

[image]

Screen shot-2: I deleted one character(3) the cursor automatically jumped to last position of the text.[image]

How to make the cursor pointer on previous position in input textbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop cursor from jumping to end of input field in javascript replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219639/stop-cursor-from-jumping-to-end-of-input-field-in-javascript-replace)