# JS Cursor positioning with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function with onkeyup to modify the letters of text typed in uppercase.

When I tried to edit a letter in the middle of the input text the cursor will automatically position at the end of text.

I would like the cursor to keep the same position.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop cursor from jumping to end of input field in javascript replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219639/stop-cursor-from-jumping-to-end-of-input-field-in-javascript-replace)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#fname").on('input', function(){
     var start = this.selectionStart,
     end = this.selectionEnd;
     this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
     this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
```

If you want to make only first latter to upperCase and all other to Lower case. You can make it like.

```
#fname {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
#fname:first-letter {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But Please use only class for make some styles.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It works well.

Can I modify the first letter of text in uppercase and the rest in lower case?

Comment: You are welcome. It would be greate if you give me a like and check my answer like correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 <input type="text" id="fname" onkeypress="myFunction()">
 <script>
     function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("fname");
       x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();    
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need such thing.But just try `this`, it would help.

```
#fname{    
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This is using simple CSS.
If need uppercase value at the end you can try this after using that CSS.

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onfocusout="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**To uppercase first letter only:**

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

**To UpperCase all the letters**

```
this.value.toUpperCase();
```