# Be able to move the cursor with the keyboard while using a keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a function to convert uppercases to lowercases aslso  to replace white spaces for small dashes.

The problem is, when a user for example makes a typo and wants to rectify it, if he tries to move the cursor back using the keyboard, he won't be able to do so as the cursor will always be on the last position of the string.

Here I have the JS fiddle with the example working:
http://jsfiddle.net/R8N8F/7/

In the example I am using jQuery because I couldn't make it run with Javascript of jsfiddle, but this is the current function I am using:

```
function replaze(obj){
    obj.value = obj.value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
}
```

And this my HTML:

```
<input name="demo" autofocus="autofocus" onkeyup="replaze(this);" type="text" id="UserUsername">
```

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/R8N8F/4/

Comment: Thanks.I updated mine also using jQuery :) Anyway, the problem stills there.

Comment: @Steve: Works fine for me in FF 17

Comment: It does not in Chrome or Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve the selection using this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288215/96100

You could instead use my [jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/), which uses the same code. Example:

```
var $input = $("#UserUsername");
$input.keyup(function() {
    var sel = $input.getSelection();
    replaze(this);
    $input.setSelection(sel.start, sel.end);
});
```

Comment: Worked great!! I used anyway the Javascript code you posted in the original answer instead of  this jQuery one :)

Comment: @Steve: Good. I rarely use jQuery myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out 
This example help you to move cursor by arrow keys 
https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/a5ts0emr/

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/a5ts0emr/embed/"></script>
```

Comment: You should show in the question the contents of the solution and not rely on the link, as they go stale making the answer useless.