# When clicked on bold or italic tag cursor to be in middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this code in one of my torrent websites.
When you click on *'B' TAG* the next code shows up [b][/b]. However, when this is done the cursor's position is at the beginning of these tags instead of in the middle, like this: *[b]cursor here[/b]*

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BBTag(tag, s, text, form) {
    switch (tag) {
        case '[url]':
            var start = document.forms[form].elements[text].selectionStart;
            var end = document.forms[form].elements[text].selectionEnd;
            if (start != end) {
                var body = document.forms[form].elements[text].value;
                var left = body.substr(body, start);
                var middle = "[url]" + body.substring(start, end) + "[/url]";
                var right = body.substr(end, body.length);
                document.forms[form].elements[text].value = left + middle + right;
            } else {
                document.forms[form].elements[text].value = document.forms[form].elements[text].value + "[url][/url]";
            }
            document.forms[form].elements[text].focus();
    }
```

This is the code for inserting these tags:

```
<td align="center">
    <input type="button" name="url" value="URL " onclick="javascript: BBTag('[url]', 'url', '<?php echo $name; ?>', '<?php echo $form; ?>')" />
</td>
```

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [update textarea value, but keep cursor position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position), certainly the answer there answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the function with a curly bracket:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BBTag(tag, s, text, form) {
        switch (tag) {
            case '[url]':
                var start = document.forms[form].elements[text].selectionStart;
                var end = document.forms[form].elements[text].selectionEnd;
                if (start != end) {
                    var body = document.forms[form].elements[text].value;
                    var left = body.substr(body, start);
                    var middle = "[url]" + body.substring(start, end) + "[/url]";
                    var right = body.substr(end, body.length);
                    document.forms[form].elements[text].value = left + middle + right;
                } else {
                    document.forms[form].elements[text].value = document.forms[form].elements[text].value + "[url][/url]";
                }
                document.forms[form].elements[text].focus();
        }
    // You miss a function closing curly bracket here
</script>
```

I would advise you to work with clean indented code. So the next time you would spot these kind of errors.

Comment: Nope that not a problem
i want when click on B tag my cursor should be in between the tags [b]here[/b].This is not happing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use setCaretPosition() from [this website](http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/).

Instead of using

```
document.forms[form].elements[text].focus();
```

subtract "the last closed tag length" from "document.forms[form].elements[text].value length" and you get exact position where to put the cursor.

// EDIT

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NaAxn/

As I said, you have to substract closing tag length from the textarea length:

```
var pos = document.forms[form].elements[text].value.length - (tag.length + 1); // Closing tag has + 1 char because of the slash 
setCaretPosition(document.forms[form].elements[text], pos);
```

Comment: Nope didn't work please see this link
http://piratex.us/torrents-upload.php
Please provide the specific code If possible...